# Is game hacking all about memory manipulation?

Tags: c++, memory, winapi, game-hacking

I wanted to know if game hacking is all about manipulating memory ?

and If we need anything more than, this topics for game hacking ?

- memory manipulation
- Reverse engineering
- Windows internals
- C++ programming

If yes is there anything special that Rake is teaching in guidedhacking forum ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. The scope of your question is quite broad, is there a specific technical challenge or problem you are facing? There are a large number of game hacking resources publicly available, including at least 1 book; the topics you need to cover depend on your objectives. Manipulating the runtime behavior of, say, Stardew Valley is not the same as creating a bot to play a modern competitive online multiplayer game.